# How to parse this

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

I'm experimenting with googles url shortener goo.gl and at the moment it send the url to goo.gl and returns this:

```
{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "http://goo.gl/kyPI",
 "longUrl": "http://dsfsd.com/"
}
```

I think it's JSON but I'm having trouble with that because of ARC. Is there anyway else I could parse the string with key "id"?

Comment: Why would you be having trouble with ARC and JSON?

Comment: Most of the JSON frameworks always screw up with ARC for some reason.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization is built in to ios, use that if an external framework is giving you trouble.

Comment: @ChristopherHannah just compile the source files of the library with `-fno-objc-arc`...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Tried that but still showing the ARC errors and won't compile.

Comment: @jrturton I'm doing a Mac app, is it still the same?

Comment: Yes, as of 10.7 though, earlier OS X versions don't have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app targets iOS 5 you can use [NSJSONSeralization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class of Apple.

(Let's assume youryour received is called theData)

```
NSError *error=nil;
    id result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData options:
               NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

//to retrieve the 'kind' value of the object
    NSLog("Kind: %@",[result objectForKey:@"kind"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's JSON, you can use a framework like SBJson to parse it. See http://stig.github.com/json-framework/